# Copy fields from one column to another with criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a table called 02_Month with the following information:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Soc   |    Society     |     USD_STD     |     USD_STD_R     |
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| AB02      |    Plants       |     3.8        |      1            |
| JK01      |    Trees        |     2.4        |      1            |
| WB09      |    Bushes       |     1.2        |      3            |
| COIN      |    Flowers      |     4.6        |      2            |
| KK99      |    Stones       |     66.9       |      3            |
| TCTC      |    Ruby         |     19.0       |      5            |
| WNOL      |    Steel        |     71.1       |      7            |
|------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to copy what says in column USD_STD to USD_STD_R if the column Soc is COIN or TCTC. I want to have this at the end:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------
|     Soc   |    Society     |     USD_STD     |     USD_STD_R     |
|------------------------------------------------------------------|
| AB02      |    Plants       |     3.8        |      1            |
| JK01      |    Trees        |     2.4        |      1            |
| WB09      |    Bushes       |     1.2        |      3            |
| COIN      |    Flowers      |     4.6        |      4.6          |
| KK99      |    Stones       |     66.9       |      3            |
| TCTC      |    Ruby         |     19.0       |      19.0         |
| WNOL      |    Steel        |     71.1       |      7            |
|------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I wrote this:

```
UPDATE 02_Month
SET [02_Month].USD_STD_R = USD_STD
WHERE (([02_Month].Soc="COIN") or ([02_Month].Soc="TCTC"));
```

It is not working as expected. I suppose it's due to the `WHERE` condition. if I don't write that line it copies the entire column USD_STD in USD_STD_R.

The code I wrote prints `0` in all of the fields of USD_STD_R. Why doesn't it work and how can it be corrected?

Comment: The column STD_USD_R is not there.

Comment: USD_STD instead of STD_USD

Comment: That line was correct on my code but when I copied it here I did it wrong. It still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The following should be sufficient:

```
update [02_month] t
set t.usd_std_r = t.usd_std
where t.soc="COIN" or t.soc="TCTC"
```

A few notes:

- Since your table name starts with a number, it must be enclosed in square brackets.
- The use of `t` is merely an alias to avoid the need to repeatedly write `[02_month]`
- You can use either `t.soc="COIN" or t.soc="TCTC"` or `t.soc in ("COIN","TCTC")` both should yield the same result.
- Double-quotes `"` are typically used by MS Access, but single-quotes `'` should also be valid.

Answer (score 0):

USD_STD instead of STD_USD

Also you can use IN operator

```
    UPDATE 02_Month
    SET [02_Month].USD_STD_R = USD_STD
    FROM [02_Month]
    WHERE ([02_Month].Soc IN ('COIN','TCTC'));
```

Comment: That line was correct on my code but when I copied it here I did it wrong. It still doesn't work

Comment: What did you get when you run the query?

Comment: I get a column full of zeros

Comment: try my above answer

Comment: Error. It says: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'USD_STD FROM [02_Month]'

Answer (score 0):

Please, try with below query. string value always within ''.

```
UPDATE 02_Month 
SET USD_STD_R = USD_STD 
WHERE Soc in ('COIN','TCTC');
```

Comment: Do I have to use ' or " for strings? Does IN works like =? I just want the societies to be COIN or TCTC

Comment: Just try with "where Soc in (?,?);" It's depended on your programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner join update` as shown below.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.USD_STD_R = b.USD_STD --You can change another column here as per your need.
FROM [02_Month] a
INNER JOIN [02_Month] b ON a.soc = b.soc
    AND a.society = b.society
    AND a.USD_STD = b.USD_STD
    AND a.USD_STD_R = b.USD_STD_R
    WHERE a.Soc in ('COIN','TCTC');
```

[Live Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=346b9f0048699e89e2b5fbd2d2e4b765)

If you do not want alias name for updating table.

```
UPDATE [02_Month]
SET [02_Month].USD_STD_R = b.USD_STD --You can change another column here as per your need.
FROM [02_Month] 
INNER JOIN [02_Month] b ON [02_Month].soc = b.soc
    AND [02_Month].society = b.society
    AND [02_Month].USD_STD = b.USD_STD
    AND [02_Month].USD_STD_R = b.USD_STD_R
    WHERE [02_Month].Soc in ('COIN','TCTC');
```

[db<>fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9174d86e426953bd3f4f10155a630c42)

Comment: But what if the table is the same? Should I write [02_Month] instead of a and b?

Comment: @Unnamed Here I have also used the same table, Here a and b are just the alias name. You can write anything as alias while joining a table for your preferences.

Comment: But do I have to write instead of a and b?

Comment: I didn't understand what you said

Comment: @Unnamed I have removed a in my updated answer. But b is still there because single table [02_Month] is used twice. Suppose if you need one more time then you can write it as [02_Month] c, [02_Month] d, etc.

Comment: @Unnamed Please read this post - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

your relation 02_month with column field USD_STD USD_STD_R but in update statement column field name is STD_USD_R and STD_USD.

Comment: Hi @vikas_ved! Please consider clarifying and formatting your answer or/and adding a code snippet. Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a comment not answer really. You should update your answer properly.